# Unable to display new empty array after push method() using for loop- AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>User Management- M&M</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="images/logo.jpg">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/userApp.js"></script>

    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">-->
    <!--<link href="CSS/Home.css" rel="stylesheet" />-->
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myController">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="mainNav">
        <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand js-scroll-trigger" href="index.html">
                <img src="images/logo.jpg" alt="M&M" width="110" />
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="LoginPage.html">Login</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link active js-scroll-trigger" href="User_Mgmt.html">User Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="CompanyManagement.html">Company Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="ProductPage.html">Product Management</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link js-scroll-trigger" href="ShoppingCart_Group5_Team1.html">Shopping Cart</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <header class="subhead">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="ex3" type="text" placeholder="Search Users" ng-model="searchUsers">
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg float-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Add New</button>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
            </div>

            <hr>


            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr class="table100-head">
                        <th>Email</th>
                        <th>First Name</th>
                        <th>Last Name</th>
                        <th>Contact</th>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="user in selectedUsers | filter: searchUsers track by $index">
                        <td>{{user.email}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.firstName}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.lastName}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.contact}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.role}}</td>
                        <td>{{user.company}}</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-info" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalEdit" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Edit</button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModalDelete" ng-click="selectUser(user)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        </header>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to create a webpage where when a user logs in, depending on the login user's company, I need to display select list of users from the "Users" Array.

The problem is after the push()method, the consolelog and debug both display the data in the selectedUsers list, but not in the browser.

For eg- When a user belonging to company Apple logs in, then here int he table, only users belonging to company APPLE should be displayed.

For reference- "currentUser" is the array taken from login Page using localStorage.getItem().

"users" array includes the list of all users from various companies.

"selectedUsers" an empty array where only users belonging to one company should be displayed. This is done by using for loop for users array with currentUser array. After that I push the filtered users data into selectedUsers array and display them in a table.

I have heard about the function called async. Should I use that? I have no idea where and how to implement that.

Looking for guidance. Thanks in advance.

PS: Yes, I have used ng-repeat user in selectedUsers in HTML page to display selectedUsers.

```js
//Info-

    //currentUser- user array acquired from the login user page.

    // Users- List of all static users in the array.

    // selectedUsers- List of users displayed and filtered from the users array based on currentUser.company


if (localStorage.getItem("currentUser") !== null) {

        var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("currentUser"));
        console.log("Received", currentUser);
    }
    else {
        console.log("Not received");
    }
    
if (localStorage.getItem("users") === null) {
        $scope.users = [
            { email: "John@yahoo.com", password: "John123", firstName: "John", lastName: "Doe", contact: "281-283-2480", role: "Supplier-Admin", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Rick@yahoo.com", password: "Rick123", firstName: "Rick", lastName: "Fraiser", contact: "987-283-2489", role: "Supplier-User", company: "Apple" },
            { email: "Sam@yahoo.com", password: "Sam123", firstName: "Sam", lastName: "Tarly", contact: "456-786-2480", role: "BuyerAdmin", company: "Samsung" }
        ];
        localStorage.setItem("users", JSON.stringify($scope.users));
    } else {
        $scope.users = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("users"));
    }

//filter users based on currentUser's role and push into selectedUsers
    for (var i = 0; i<$scope.users.length; i++) {
        $scope.selectedUsers = [{}];
        if ($scope.users[i].company === currentUser[0].company) {
            $scope.selectedUsers.push($scope.users[i]);
        }
        console.log("filteredUsers", $scope.selectedUsers);
        localStorage.setItem("selectedUsers", JSON.stringify($scope.selectedUsers));
    }
```

Comment: Create a plunker demo we can test this in

Comment: @charlietfl Please tell me how to do that

Comment: @ryanyuyu I have added the html now :)

Comment: Plunker example http://plnkr.co/edit/4APS8ZMGreo9p0QBtFXV?p=preview . Just edit the files with your basic code and save new link

Comment: @charlietfl http://embed.plnkr.co/Kr2B5br48IMKlkvhQOpm/

Comment: script paths aren't valid in that demo

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? A searchbox to filter table content?  Why do you push the selected user to localstorage then?

Comment: @nkuma_12 Its not about the searchbox. I am trying to display users belonging to specific company taken from a pool of users in the "users" array. The users belonging to specific company is the "selectedUsers" array. This filter is done by comparing the "users.company" array with the "currentUser" array.company. Those list of users will be pushed into the "selectedUsers" array and will be displayed in the table. localStorage is used so that they will remain even after adding, editing or deleting a user.